# SQLITE3 UPDATE CASE Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sql-update

I'm using the sqllite3 npm for node.js and I want to do the following:

A player can play the game 10 times. 24 Hours later the counter resets and he can play 10 games again. My thought  was doing it with an update case.

```
 db.run("UPDATE user_sessions SET games_played = CASE WHEN((CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - CAST(strftime('%s', last_game) as integer))>86400 THEN "1" ELSE  ?1, last_game = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ip_address = ?2 AND user_agent = ?3", {
        1:gamesPlayed,
        2:handshake.address,
        3:handshake.headers['user-agent']
    });
```

He updates and sets counter 1 if between last game and now are 24 hours different (86400 seconds).

```
(CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - CAST(strftime('%s', last_game) as integer)
```

Should give the time difference in seconds. It works for me.

The complete statement doesnt work for me it says : 
error near "THEN": syntax error

Is this kind of update statement possible? If yes what im doing wrong?

I also tried this in the sqlite browser command line:

```
UPDATE user_sessions SET games_played = CASE WHEN(((CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - CAST(strftime('%s', last_game) as integer))>86400) THEN 1 ELSE  5, last_game = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Same error.

Comment: You need to end your `CASE ... WHEN THEN ... ELSE ... END` projection (with an `END`)

Comment: There is also a bracket `)` missing or one `(` extra after `WHEN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a redundant `(` before the first `cast`, and are missing the `end` clause of the `case` expression:

```
UPDATE user_sessions SET games_played = CASE WHEN(CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - CAST(strftime('%s', last_game) as integer))>86400 THEN "1" ELSE  ?1 END, last_game = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ip_address = ?2 AND user_agent = ?3"
```

Comment: Still missing `END` in `CASE` clause as stated by @StuartLC